# Transparent but Clickable JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've seen several tutorials and questions asking about transparent JFrames / JWindows / Windows, but they all have 'click-through' property where you can interact with . Is there some way to disable this feature?

Some relevant code:

```
//imports
public class Canvas extends JFrame
{
    public Canvas()
    {
        super();

        setBounds(getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds()); //set fullscreen
        setUndecorated(true);                              //remove decoration
        setBackground(new Color(0, true));                 //make transparent

        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
        setVisible(true);

        //Esc to close
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I can essentially achieve what I want by setting the background with a low alpha setting:

```
setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 1)); //1 alpha (1 out of 255)
```

However, this is more a hack than a real solution. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: ...Can't really be done as that's kind of the point...so, yeah, you're hack is probably the best choice you have...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I understand this seems redundant, but there is valid reasons for wanting a transparent, non-click-through program. Is there perhaps an alternative way to approach this problem instead? (Using a different component for example)

Comment: This is how per-pixel alphaering works. Even if you used a different component, you'd still end up at the same place

Comment: Use "JFrame#setExentedState" and pass it "JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH", this prevent the window from been hidden behind things like the taskbar. Also, generally speaking, KeyListener isn't your friend, use Key Bindings instead...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Alright, I shall just use a low alpha background. Thanks for your assistance and improvements (using Key Bindings now).

Comment: *"but there is valid reasons for wanting a transparent, non-click-through program."*  **Spy Bot.**  ..Can you name another?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Three others: 1) (my reason) A game that uses a possibly active/user generated background for gameplay. 2) To allow drawing on the screen. 3) A program where you can place stuff on the screen, eg; drag out a rectangle to use as a sticky note. Note that for a "Spy Bot", it would be beneficial to click-through.